# How to save the data into two databases in CakePHP

Tags: php, database, cakephp

In my `app/Config/database.php` I have a setup which looks like this,

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'default_db',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);

public $second = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'second_db',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

Now what I wanted was to simultaneously save the data, wherever and whenever I am saving any kind of data. This databases are identical, that is why I want to save the data to both databases to maintain them being identical. Where would I edit such that all the `save/edit/update/delete` processes will both save to both databases. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

in my `lib/Cake/Model/Model.php` is a line of code which looks like this

```
/**
* The name of the DataSource connection that this Model uses
*
* The value must be an attribute name that you defined in `app/Config/database.php`
* or created using `ConnectionManager::create()`.
*
* @var string
* @link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usedbconfig
*/
public $useDbConfig = 'default';
```

is there where I should start editing to be able to save the data into two databases? Thanks.

Comment: Why not use replication at the database level? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: I also highly recommend using the replication at the database level. This ensures that CakePHP is doing its job and eliminates room for any errors or server timeout, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Doing this through CakePHP is slow and not necessary, why aren't you using a feature like [DB replication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_(computing))? However, you can change the connection the model us using through the model property [useDbConfig](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/source-class-Model.html#47-56).

```
$this->save($data);
$this->useDbConfig = 'second';
$this->save($data, array('callbacks' => false, 'validate' => false);
$this->useDbConfig = 'default';
```

You could add the last three lines of the above code to your `Model::afterSave()` callback, or much better, do it via a [behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html) and attach it to each model that needs it.

Comment: When you say `add the last three lines of the above code to your Model::afterSave()` you mean i need to edit `public function afterSave(Model $model, $created, $options = array()) {
  
  
  return true;
 }`

Comment: No, I said to create a behavior with that code. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html Because it will avoid that you have to copy and paste it in every model. If you don't know how to do it I can write that behavior for you, just contact me.

Comment: be my guest please. Thank you very much in advance. :)